# How to assign columns based on caracter position?

Tags: r, datatables

My data file doesn't have any columns classification and the row1 looks like this:

```
AB365960091120112011311260000005311300000001ES020000040036ES1400N
```

I know that characters from 1 to 8 data refer to ID, from 9 to 15 refer to year of birth, from 16 to 28 refer to year of dead and so on. How can I create a table separate according to the character position? What is the way to indicate that ID = character from 1 to 8, for example in R lenguage?

I want my table to look like this:

```
ID           birth date             death date

AB36596      9112011               201131126
```

Comment: I've added R language tag. You are probably looking for the substring() function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read_fwf` from `readr` package.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df <- read_fwf(file = "test.txt", fwf_widths(c(9, 7, 9))) %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("id", "birth date", "death date"))
df
```

**Output is:**

```
  id        `birth date` `death date`
1 AB3659600      9112011    201131126
```

**Sample data:**

`test.txt` having

```
AB365960091120112011311260000005311300000001ES020000040036ES1400N
```

Comment: Instead of `colnames<-` you can use the pipe-friendly `setNames`. No need for backticks or arrows!

Comment: Thanks! It works well. I have another doubt, because I have to search and generate another file with data from column ID containing "FR" at the beginning of the code. I'm trying to do that using filtro<-grep("FR", Data$ID, ignore.case=FALSE)
Date[filtro,], but I don't sure whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution based on your example:

Input data:

```
x<-"AB365960091120112011311260000005311300000001ES020000040036ES1400N"
```

Split the string in each variable and add them in a data.frame

```
df<-data.frame(ID=substr(x,1,7),
 birth_date=substr(x,10,16),
 death_date=substr(x,17,25))
```

Your desired output

```
df
       ID birth_date death_date
1 AB36596    9112011  201131126
```

Using the same approach and `substr` function you will be able to extract all information.